# How do I put "of people" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Consider this

> The word "contradict" means to say the opposite of what someone else has said.

I guess the sentence above is clear and natural as it is adapted [from Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contradict).

In fact, that page also contains "(of people)" in the definition of the word.

How do I put "of people" in the adapted quotation, to make a complete sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question is based on a misunderstanding of the dictionary definition.

> **contradict**
> (of people) to say the opposite of what someone else has said, or (of one fact or statement) to be so different from another fact or statement that one of them must be wrong

The words "of people" and "of one fact or statement" appear in parenthesis to mark that there are two parts to this definition - one that can be said *of people*, the other that can be said *of facts or statements*. In other words, you can contradict a *person* **or** you can contradict a *fact*.

> Examples:
>
> - I contradicted him. <--(of people)
> - That contradicts his statement. <-- (of one fact or statement)

It doesn't mean that you can insert the words "of people" into the examples. The sentence you quoted as an example is complete.

Answer (score 0):

The note (of people) means that  that is the definition of *contradict* when a *person* does it. They give another definition that applies when one *statement* contradicts another.

*The word 'contradict', when used of a person, means...*