# Did I interpret the parenthesis correctly?

Tags: meaning

The parenthesis in definitions of words on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/grammar) confuses me [a lot](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/252437/115409).

[image]

Regarding the one shown above, could I interpret the definition as the combination of following three sentences?

> "grammar" usually means the rules about how words change their form and combine with other words to make sentences;

> "grammar" could also mean the study of those rules;

> "grammar" could also mean the use of those rules.

Comment: [*Parenthesis*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parentheses): "**1 a** : an amplifying (see amplify sense 1) or explanatory word, phrase, or sentence inserted in a passage from which it is usually set off by punctuation // explained further in a *parenthesis*." [*Amplify*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amplify): "**1** : to expand (something, such as a statement) by the use of detail or illustration or by closer analysis." It doesn't mean *could also*; it means *to clarify*.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have interpreted it correctly. The word "grammar" can refer to

(1) a set of rules about words...

(2) the use of that set of rules

or

(3) the study of that set of rules